# Laravel 5.3 - image upload not working

Tags: file-upload, laravel-5.3

I have an input field for image upload in my view:

```
              <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image">
```

I have created folder uploads in my public folder and in my Controller I am trying to upload a file like this:

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('uploads/', 'public');
```

When I submit the form and upload an image nothing gets uploaded to the folder uploads and I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'image' doesn't have a
>   default value

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to put enctype and files on your form ->
 enctype="multipart/form-data" files="true"